# FileSystemWatcher ArgumentException

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble understanding how FileSystemWatcher is supposed to work. I'm trying to get my code to wait for a file to exist, and then call on another function. My code is as follows:

> string path2 = @"N:\reuther\TimeCheck\cavmsbayss.log";

```
        FileSystemWatcher fw = new FileSystemWatcher(path2);
       fw.Created += fileSystemWatcher_Created;
```

Then I have a seperate function that should handle the file once its event is called:

```
        static void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ok im here now");
    }
```

But it

The directory name N:\reuther\TimeCheck\cavmsbayss.log is invalid.

Comment: Is there no way to have it watch for a file to be created?

Comment: What's the problem to check directory for specified file creation event? Filter it by name or other params from all events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b36854c3(v=vs.110).aspx), the `path` parameter indicates:

> The directory to monitor, in standard or Universal Naming Convention (UNC) notation.

Pass it the path to the directory, not the particular file:

```
string pathToMonitor = @"N:\reuther\TimeCheck";
FileSystemWatcher fw = new FileSystemWatcher(pathToMonitor);
fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  // the default is false, you may have to set this too
fw.Created += fileSystemWatcher_Created;
```

Then just watch out for the creation of that file, using either the `Name` or `FullPath` property in the [`FileSystemEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
static void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Name == "cavmsbayss.log")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ok im here now");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with that code... I tried to use it:

string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

            string path2 = desktopPath + @"\" + @"RaidTimestamps\";

            FileSystemWatcher fw = new FileSystemWatcher(path2);
           fw.Created += fileSystemWatcher_Created;

        static void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Name);
            if (e.Name == "orvmsnw1ss.log")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ok im here now");
            }
        }

Comment: With the above, nothing is showing at all. Meaning the code isn't executing even though I know the path is 100% correct.

Comment: I did: 

MessageBox.Show(e.Name);

And no, it didn't hit at all.

Comment: Oh my sweet jesus, you Grant, are a life saver.

Comment: @vivat pisces , my folder name location is c:\windows\system32\foldername , its giving exception:System.ArgumentException: The directory name 'C:\Windows\System32\foldername' does not exist . Its working fine from visual studio but gives exception from windows service.